# How get value in object JavaScript by number

Tags: javascript

Get the property value a javascript object is easy:

```
var t = {a:"hi"}
t.a //print "hi"
```

But for the next object, the same idea does not work:

```
var t = {0:"hi"}
t.0 //Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number
```

How to get value of t.0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `t['0']`. If a key can't be syntactically placed after the dot, you need to use this syntax.

Your first example could be similarly rewritten to `t['hi']`.

It's worth pointing out that the key is not a number at all. It's a string with the value `'0'`.

Comment: "If a key can't be syntactically placed after the dot" --- +1'd, but it would be even more helpful if the rules or at least a tiny excerpt of those was provided on what is syntactically valid to be used there and what is not.

Comment: @zerkms "If the key cannot be used a valid variable identifier (`var not-valid;` for example) then it must be accessed via the square bracket syntax"? I'm curious how you would provide the rules?

Comment: @zerkms It's invalid syntax when using dots for a variable to start with a number, it includes properties as well.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek well, I can check the standard with no problem, my suggestion addressed the answer improvement

Comment: The expression inside the square brackets need not be a string, `t[0]` is also valid. What's important to notice is that square brackets take an expression, while the dot syntax expects [a valid identifier](https://mothereff.in/js-variables)

Comment: `t[0]` is valid (and works) but a little sloppy in this case, since the key is actually the string `'0'`.

Comment: @Hailwood it is defined there http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-left-hand-side-expressions In short - it must be a valid identifier, and the rules for identifiers are not complicated.

Comment: `t['0']` can be kind of misleading in this example. If you have an object like `var t = { 0b1 : 1 }`, you don't access it with `t['0b1']` but with `t[1]`, `t[0b1]` or `t['1']`.